# Connecting MySQL v5.6 database to Delphi XE7 using dbExpress MySQLConnection

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbexpress

Hi I'm trying to connect my MYSQL server to my delphi application using the dbExpress MySQL connection using MYSQL v5.6 and delphi XE7. When trying to connect I get the following error:
[image]

does anyone know if these versions are incompatible, I read online about a .dll file that could be missing, does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Do you put the `libmysql.dll` file on your exe or system path?

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know where to get this library file for my version or what directory it belongs in do you?

Comment: You can found that file in the `lib` folder where the MySQL server is installed or download from the MySQL site,

Comment: Where do I put the file so delphi can access it?

Comment: In the same folder of your exe or in the system path.

Comment: I copied the file from MySQL to the bin folder in the dir but I still have the error

Comment: Check the version of the libmysql.dll, maybe is not supported by the dbexpress driver. Also check which the dll had the same bitness (32 or 64 bits) of your app

Comment: How do I check the version of the libmysql?

Comment: There is zero reason to include the image in this question. It would be much clearer if you copied the text of the error and put it in your post as text, where it is actually readable. It's much more friendly to people who are using mobile devices (who won't be able to read the message at all, and who have to spend their data capacity to retrieve it for no reason) and those behind some corporate proxies that don't allow the image site at all. Use images only when *absolutely necessary* because you can't clearly demonstrate the problem any other way.